# How do I see which ports are open?

Tags: server, firewall

I am running a web server on a machine with Ubuntu 11.
Everything is accessible from the local network, but not from outside.
What can I do to check to make sure the appropriate ports are open?

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and server management, so any "dumbing down" is just fine.

Appreciate any help.  Google search hasn't given me much actionable advice.